# Left/Right channel balance stereo is not working for Apple Airpods(Bluetooth)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit to create an experimental iOS audio application. 
Currently, I am trying to record and playback audio on only one speaker (Left/Right Stereo) at a time, But it is playing on both speakers after setting left/right stereo channel(Slider balance control from Settings > General > Accessibility > slider Left/Right channel).

Actually, I need to record and playback audio on left or right Apple Airpods headphone only. When left/right channel settings are changed on Accessibility.

```
   AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
   do {
       try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
   } catch {
       AKLog("Could not set session category.")
   }

    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    AKSettings.useBluetooth = true
    // Patching
    inputPlot.node = mic
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

   // Will set the level of microphone monitoring
    micBooster.gain = 1
   recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)

    if let file = recorder.audioFile {

        player = try? AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
   }

    player.looping = true
    player.completionHandler = playingEnded

    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(player)

    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, micBooster)

    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    AudioKit.start()
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for recording sound only on one airpod?